# Building and publishing multiple executables for ClickOnce application

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, clickonce, publish

I'm working on a C# ClickOnce application that is meant to launch another background process after it starts. I know that ClickOnce is only designed to work with one application, so I'm trying to figure out if there's some way I can include the extra executable file as a resource. I can include the project for the extra executable in my solution, so ideally I want to build the executable first before including it.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10592381/2452803) is very close to what I need, but it seems to have one significant flaw - if another team member checks out the repository for the first time, the executable doesn't exist yet, and the build will fail before it starts. Basically it needs an existing executable there first in order to work, and that won't be guaranteed.

(Also, the Best Answer on that page doesn't appear to work, as I get an error when trying to install the ClickOnce application after publishing. I tried following the instructions on [this page](http://go4answers.webhost4life.com/Example/clickonce-error-referencing-multiple-17671.aspx) to solve it, to no avail.)

Comment: _"the build will fail before it starts"_ - incorrect. Just set up an explicit project dependency

Comment: One option is to include the functionality of the background executable in the main one, but switch mode using using command line parameters.