# Packaging WPF App with several entry points

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, packaging

I developed an app in c#. The solution contains several projects among which :

- a wpf project for the front
- a consol app called "web" that exposes the backend through a collection of API (I used the "ASP.NET Core Web API" Template)

From Visual Studio, When I launch the App, I use "multiple startup projects" so Visual Studio launches the web project (the backend) and launches the WPF project (the frontend) in parrallel.

I want to package my app. For the moment, I dont want to publish it on the Windows store, just packaging it locally which is called sideloading. I did it and it ended successfully. I then install the app from the package on my local machine.

**Problem:  When I start my app I just have the consol running. I checked from Postman and my web project correctly runs. But the WPF app is not started.**

In the project related to packaging (I called it installer), I have specified the appxmanifest, the temporarykey.pfx and in Dependencies->Applications I can find my two projects (wpf and web)

When I right click on wpf, I can select "set as entry point". When I repack my app, then the wpf project launches, but not the console for the backend anymore. Indeed, when I select "set as entry point" then the web project is not an entry point anymore.

So my question is : How can I/Is it possible to package an App with several entry points ?

[image: screenshot of my solution]

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume you are using ClickOnce when you publish since you mentioned side-loading. ClickOnce is really finicky about multiple exe's in a single package (Just one of many security mechanisms that can possibly get in your specific way)

You can read more about some of the pain points here:

- [How do I publish multiple applications / processes with one clickonce deployment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10590846/how-do-i-publish-multiple-applications-processes-with-one-clickonce-deployment)
- [Eight Evil Things Microsoft Never Showed You in the ClickOnce Demos (and What You Can Do About Some of Them)](https://www.codemag.com/article/0902031/Eight-Evil-Things-Microsoft-Never-Showed-You-in-the-ClickOnce-Demos-and-What-You-Can-Do-About-Some-of-Them)

Windows Store has many of the same security restrictions when publishing so familiarizing yourself if you plan on using it for distribution.

Other options are packaging your MSI yourself using [WIX](https://wixtoolset.org/) or other installer frameworks.

If your WPF app is dependent on the console app, I suggest you convert it to a [Worker Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/workers) so its always running without needing to be launched.

Comment: thank you Anthony I am gonna have a look to your suggestions