# how to get administrator confirmation for certain action in my clickonce application?

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, clickonce

i'm developing an application which should display a standard Windows popup with "Need administrative permission to continue" when user chooses to do certain action in my appliucation (adding it to firewall white list). Otherwise it just fails. How can I achieve that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't run ClickOnce app as admin - but you can spawn a process from it which will get admin rights - and then you can make that process to do what you need: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10228137/1246870

you can create console exe file and distribute it with your ClickOnce app.